# How to update original binary search tree and return a new tree?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to do a function that

1. takes a value as an argument and return a new binary search tree with values smaller than it,

   *meanwhile*
2. removing these same values from the original tree

   I'm trying not to use delete node function, this is what I've got so far

```
//output: it returns the new tree with the smaller values but no update is being made on the original tree
template < class T >
BST < T > BST < T >::NewTree (T & data)
{
  T *lst = getAllData ();

  BST < T > ret;

  node < T > *p = root;
  node < T > *parent = n;

/*I'm trying here to delete the smaller nodes from the original tree, it's not working,
is there a way I can do the two operations,
inserting the values into the new tree, 
and deleting those same values from the original tree simultaneously? */

  while (p != NULL)
    {
      if (p->val == v)  
      break;
      parent = p;   

      if (p->val > v)
    {           
      p = p->left;
      parent->left == NULL; 

    }
      else
      p = p->right;

    }                           

  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) // 7 is the number of elements, I didn't add getSize func.
    {
      if (lst[i] < data)
    {
      ret.insert (lst[i]); // insert all the values smaller than data in my new tree, 
                           //this part is working fine

    }
    }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: If p points to the original tree, i expect to see in the code updates to p->left and/or p->right. I do not see such statements, thus indeed your code does not modify the original tree. there are other issues with this code, e.g. the new tree is being allocated on the stack.

Comment: @nivpeled yes p points to the original tree. I'm already updating p=p->left if val is larger than v and p=p->right for else, Where should I also modify it?

Comment: you must have in your code `p->left = <something>` or `p->right = <something>` in order to actually modify the tree. You currently do not have such statements